# How to reassign an object property to a different type without making Flow angry

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

In the code that follows, there exists a `role` property with the following type:

```
type RoleT = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
};
```

However, that property will ultimately get reassigned to either a number or a string towards the bottom of the function. This appears to cause Flow to no longer understand the type of the property **prior** to the assignment.

```
type FormValuesT = {
  role?: RoleT[],
};

function normalizeFormValues(formValues: FormValuesT): * {
  const values = { ...formValues };

  if (!values.role) return values;
  if (!values.role.length) {
    delete values.role;
    return values;
  }

  const firstRole = values.role[0];
  values.role = firstRole.id || firstRole.name; // `role` is reassigned to a new type

  if (!values.role) delete values.role;

  return values;
}
```

Flow has two complaints on the line `const firstRole = values.role[0];`:

> Computed property/element cannot be accessed on property `id` of unknown type
>   Computed property/element cannot be accessed on number

And on the next line:

> property `name` Property not found in String

I assume this has something to do with [this bit in the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-reassigning-unsealed-object-properties):

> if you reassign a property of an unsealed object, by default Flow will give it the type of all possible assignments.

Is there a simple solution to helping Flow understand what's going on?